# Identityserver4 Callback isuue

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I'm using identityserver4 with .Net core 3.0 Azure AD authentication for my application.
When user logged in to Microsoft account successfully it should be redirect to angular client application.
Unfortunately I'm getting below error when redirects to the client application.

[image]

Below is my OIDC configuration

```
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Demo IdentityServer", options =>
            {
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async ctx =>
                    {
                        var message = ctx.ProtocolMessage;
                        ctx.Properties.Items[OpenIdConnectDefaults.UserstatePropertiesKey] = message.State;
                    }

                };
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.Authority = "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                options.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                options.ClientSecret = "L-soqX=3N8kIU0y1gDbB=Ws_QqAMUw@[";
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                    //,RoleClaimType = "role"
                };

            });
        return services;
```

This is my call back method.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
    {
        // read external identity from the temporary cookie
        try
        {
            var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
            if (result?.Succeeded != true)
            {
                throw new Exception("External authentication error");
            }

            if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
            {
                var externalClaims = result.Principal.Claims.Select(c => $"{c.Type}: {c.Value}");
                _logger.LogDebug("External claims: {@claims}", externalClaims);
            }

            // lookup our user and external provider info
            var (user, provider, providerUserId, claims) = FindUserFromExternalProvider(result);
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = AutoProvisionUser(provider, providerUserId, claims);
            }
            var additionalLocalClaims = new List<Claim>();
            var localSignInProps = new AuthenticationProperties();
            ProcessLoginCallbackForOidc(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);
            var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.SubjectId)
            {
                DisplayName = user.Username,
                IdentityProvider = provider,
                AdditionalClaims = additionalLocalClaims
            };

            await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(provider, providerUserId, user.SubjectId, user.Username));
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.Username, provider, localSignInProps, additionalLocalClaims.ToArray());
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

            // retrieve return URL
            var returnUrl = result.Properties.Items["returnUrl"] ?? "~/";

            // check if external login is in the context of an OIDC request
            var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);

            //await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(provider, providerUserId, user.SubjectId, user.Username, true, context?.ClientId));



            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciate in advance.

Comment: From the message it seems that the problem is in the UserStore. Is the Id of your ApplicationUser a Guid?

Comment: By the way, you should make a habit of redacting sensitive information, like secrets. Even when they are only used for local testing.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg yes I have added identitye user like services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>>

Comment: `UserManager.FindByIdAsync` calls `ConvertIdToString` that expects a guid but the parameter provided isn't of the correct format. What does the value of the `sub` claim look like?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I have change the Identityuser as original(removed the GUID) now Authorize/callback event trigger infinite loop(going to Microsoft login page and again redirecting to it) Any advice would be appreciate

Comment: You should ask a new question for that since that seems an entirely different issue. Then you'll have better changes in getting it answered. Do include the relevant information, logging, etc. that can help in understanding what is happening.